# retrying a request after it failed

Tags: ios, networking

I am using the default classes provided by app to do my networking tasks in my app.

At some point, some of my requests time out (regardless of the reason for the timeout)

I would like to retry some of these requests

I have subclassed the NSURLConnection class and added some parameters to it.

However, in the method "connection:didFailWithError:"

con.retries seems to always be 1, never incremented. Why ?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did recieve error: %@", [error description]]);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[error userInfo]description]]);
WBURLConnection *con = (WBURLConnection *)connection;
if([con shouldRetryRequest:error]){
    con.retries ++;
    [con start];
}else{
    [con cancel];
    [con.data  setLength:0];
    if(!self.alert){
        self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [self.alert show];
    }else {
        if(![self.alert isVisible]){
            [self.alert show];
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
-(BOOL)shouldRetryRequest:(NSError *)error{
    [self.retryCount appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%ld",error,(long)self.retries]];
    LogInfo(@"retries:%@",self.retryCount);
    if([error code] == -1004){
        return NO;
    }
    return self.retries<3;
}
```

Comment: Rather than calling `start` on the connection that just failed, I'd be inclined to instantiate a new `NSURLConnection`.